# How to show non-popular checkboxes on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, user-interface, checkbox

In a form I've got a list of about 15 checkboxes, of which 3 are the most popular. So by default I only want to show the 3 popular choices. At the end of the 3 checkboxes there should be an icon to expand and collapse the rest of the checkboxes.

I'm building the website in Angular, so I guess I can simply use an `ng-show` for this. The thing is that I wonder whether that is the correct way to do this. It seems to me that this is such a common thing, that there should be some kind of standard way of doing this..?

And also what kind of icon do people normally use for this? For expand and collapse I would normally use the little grey triangle, but I feel it doesn't suit this specific situation well. I know I've seen this before in other forms, but I just can't find it anymore to take inspiration from.

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ng-show` for a similar purpose in my application and it works well.  I set the default value in my controller and then make the `ng-click` event trigger a toggle.

Controller:

```
$scope.expanded = false;
```

Html:

```
<div ng-show="!expanded">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" title="Expand"  ng-click="expanded=true">
</div>
<div ng-show="expanded">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" title="Collapse" ng-click="expanded=false">
</div>
```

As for icons, I like to use bootstrap glyphicons.  The `glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top` and `glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom` are good for collapse/expand, as well as `glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign` and `glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign`. You can find more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

Comment: Awesome! Also the tip on the plus and minus sign are exactly what I hoped for!